# How to access beans loaded in common jar in different web applications deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

I'd like to know the best way to load shared jars into Tomcat so that two or more WAR's deployed in Tomcat are able to access Spring Beans from common jars without any issues.

When I'm deploying more than one WAR into Tomcat, beans in common jars are getting overwritten every time an application is deployed. How can I configure or load common jars that every application deployed in Tomcat gets its own set of beans without overwriting any other application beans.

I'm loading common jars from shared path.. Tomcat loads jar from its lib directory, then from shared location then from `WEB-INF/lib[.war]` and so on...                                                                                        My Question here is, how to load jars which are shared between multiple web applications. I also wanna ensure that spring beans loaded in one application context are isolated from others.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand your meaning. In java web, the jars are loaded by class loader based on some strategy. If your jars are in lib directory of tomcat, every application deployed in this tomcat can load these jars from tomcat lib directory.

And if the jars are in your war packages, every application will load from it own war package.

In the normal, we will not put any jars into tomcat lib by ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mavlam. I am loading common jars from shared path.. Tomcat loads jar from its lib directory, then from shared location then from WEB-INF/lib[.war] and so on...                                                                                        My Question here is, how to load jars which are shared between multiple web applications. I also wanna ensure that spring beans loaded in one application context are isolated from others.

Comment: For java web app, every application has it own class loader, which will load all necessary classes from jre_lib -> tomcat_lib -> war_lib and app classes. Although one class loaded from same jar maybe in 2 web apps, they are 2 different Objects (the Class objects), and their instances created from those class are different class types.  And if only one class is loaded, it will not be loaded again even if the jar updated. Another point is, the different web app have their own application context, you can not access or affect other beans in other web app.

Comment: About class loader of java web app, you can refer this:http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rjc301/